# Confusion in CT Fourier Transform Proof

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals

I am confused trying to understand the Proof of Fourier Transform from Oppenheim book *Signals and Systems*. I am pasting the equations directly from the book:

> $$\widetilde{x}(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_ke^{jk\omega_0t} \tag{4.3} $$
>   $$a_k=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}\widetilde{x}(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt \tag{4.4} $$
>
> where $\omega_0=2\pi/T$. Since $\widetilde{x}(t)=x(t)$ for $|t| < T/2$, and also, since $x(t)=0$ outside this interval, eq. $(4.4)$ can be
>   rewritten as
>
> $$a_k=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}x(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt$$

1. My question is In the last equation on the L.H.S, there is no
   $\widetilde{x}(t)$ but it was mentioned in the eq. $(4.4)$
2. And then we have: $$Ta_k= \left.\frac{2 \sin(\omega T_1)}{\omega}\right\rvert_{\omega =
   k\omega_0}$$ That is, with $\omega$ thought of as a continuous variable, the function ($2\sin\omega T_1/ \omega$) represents envelope of $Ta_k$.
   Here I want to know what is meant by envelope?I want to add more details from the book exactly " Specifically we have plot $T_0a_k$ rather than $a_k$ and we have also modified the horizontal spacing in each plot. here is the plot "
   [image]
   c) I want to know that how $T_0a_k$ will be drawn in continuous?

Comment: $\tilde x(t)=x(t)$, read all.

Comment: Yes $x'(t)=x(t) for |t|< T/2$  what that means

Comment: can you do the Riemann integral?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson can you please explain exactly the answer?

Answer (score 2):

> @robertbristow-johnson can you please explain exactly the answer?

oh dear.  it's a lot of work and it should be in *some* textbook.

okay, using your O&S notation:

$$ \tilde{x}(t) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_k \ e^{j k \omega_0 t} $$

where

$$ \tilde{x}(t) = \tilde{x}(t+T) \quad \forall t $$

$$ \omega_0 \triangleq \frac{2 \pi}{T} $$

and

$$ a_k = \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0 + T} \tilde{x}(t) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 t} \ dt $$

and where $t_0$ can be any real value:  $-\infty < t_0 < +\infty$

we choose $t_0$ to be $t_0 = -\frac{T}{2}$ so that

$$ a_k = \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} \tilde{x}(t) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 t} \ dt $$

That's [Fourier Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

A [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) is a sum of areas of rectangles that, for decently well-behaved functions, converges to the area of an integral in the limit that the rectangles get thinner and thinner:

$$ \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} f(t) \ dt  =  \lim_{N \to +\infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} f\left(t_1 + n\frac{t_2 - t_1}{N} \right) \ \frac{t_2 - t_1}{N} $$

for $t_1 < t_2$.

this ([Riemann integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral)) works for most ordinary functions that are decently well-behaved.  for nastier functions, [another method of defining integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) may have to be used, but we're not dealing with that here.

so do you understand Fourier series and Riemann integration?

now, define

$$ \tilde{x}(t) =
\begin{cases}
x(t), & \text{if } |t| < \frac{T}{2}  \\
x(t - mT), & \text{if } |t| > \frac{T}{2} \text{ and where } m \triangleq \left\lfloor \frac{t}{T} + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor
\end{cases} $$

$\lfloor u \rfloor$ is the $\operatorname{floor}(u)$ function that is equal to the largest integer no larger the argument $u$.  (it's always rounding down.)  $\left\lfloor u + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor$ is always rounding to nearest.

you can see that $\tilde{x}(t)$ satisfies periodicity:  $ \tilde{x}(t) = \tilde{x}(t+T) \quad \forall t $.  and you can also see that

$$ x(t) = \lim_{T\to +\infty} \tilde{x}(t) \quad \forall t $$

so we're taking a finite section of $x(t)$ and periodically extending that to get $\tilde{x}(t)$.  but as the period gets longer and longer and goes to $\infty$ the periodic extension becomes the same as $x(t)$.

now if you plug in $a_k$ into the Fourier sum:

$$ \tilde{x}(t) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} \tilde{x}(u) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 u} \ du \ e^{j k \omega_0 t} $$

and let $T \to +\infty$ ...

okay, i got back to this.  (sorry for the delay.)

so we've been saying

$$ \begin{align}
x(t) & = \lim_{T \to \infty} \tilde{x}(t) \\
& = \lim_{T \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} \tilde{x}(u) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 u} \ du \ e^{j k \omega_0 t}  \\
& = \lim_{T \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} x(u) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 u} \ du \ e^{j k \omega_0 t}  \\
\end{align} $$

(note the subtle difference between the last two lines.  why can we do that?)

and we're saying

$$ \begin{align}
\int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} x(u) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 u} \ du & = \lim_{N \to +\infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x\left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{+\frac{T}{2} - (-\frac{T}{2})}{N} \right) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 \left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{+\frac{T}{2} - (-\frac{T}{2})}{N} \right)} \   \frac{+\frac{T}{2} - (-\frac{T}{2})}{N} \\
& = \lim_{N \to +\infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x\left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{T}{N} \right) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 \left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{T}{N} \right)} \   \frac{T}{N} \\
\end{align} $$

putting the two limits together:

$$ \begin{align}
x(t) & = \lim_{T \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} x(u) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 u} \ du \ e^{j k \omega_0 t}  \\
& = \lim_{T \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{T} \lim_{N \to +\infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x\left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{T}{N} \right) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 \left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{T}{N} \right)} \   \frac{T}{N} \ e^{j k \omega_0 t}  \\
& = \lim_{T \to \infty} \lim_{N \to +\infty} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}   \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x\left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{T}{N} \right) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 \left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{T}{N} \right)} \   \frac{T}{N} \ e^{j k \omega_0 t} \frac{1}{T}  \\
& = \lim_{N \to +\infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \lim_{T \to \infty}  \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}    x\left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{T}{N} \right) \ e^{-j k \omega_0 \left(-\frac{T}{2} + n\frac{T}{N} \right)} \   \frac{1}{N} \ e^{j k \omega_0 t}  \\
\end{align} $$

(answer not done yet, still being developed.)

Comment: i have to quit now.  i'll return to this later.  but you should be able to see where i am going with it.

Comment: i'd also be happy if someone else finishes this.  bye for now.

Comment: I understand the part of Fourier series, but I am confused that why we are doing Riemann Sum? is it related to the second part of my question, Evelope?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, grab a + for this effort of re-writing book chapter ;)

Comment: @jojek common i need the answer.. help me if you can..

Comment: as you can see i still have a problem with $\frac{T}{N}$ which is indeterminate.  so i still have to fix it.  where i am trying to get to is: $$ x(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(u)  e^{-j \omega u} du \ e^{j \omega t} \ d\omega $$ and identifying the inner integral as $X(j \omega)$ .  i'll get back to this tomorrow, i think.  (anyone else is free to fix and finish it.)

Comment: the envelope is the function that gives the outline of the coefficients of the fourier series. while fourier series gives you coefficients $a_{k}$, but the envelope of the series $a_{k}$ is simply a smooth curve representing $a_{k}$.